# make section headings invisible?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents

Simple question here: how to make section headings invisible, but still get the correct list of sections in the TOC and headers ? e.g. on page 10, if I do a `\section{New section}`, I must not see the text "X. New section", but I still want the section to be in the TOC and in the `\rightmark` of the following pages, until a new section of course.

I'm using a minimalistic document (class article, with no package that are used to adjust section headings style)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which document class do you use: `book`, `report`, ...? Also, do you already use a package (such as `titlesec` and `sectsty`) that may be used affect the appearance of sectioning headers. Finally, do you want to suppress the appearance of all sectioning headers (including subsections, subsubsections, etc) or "just" `section`-level headers?

Comment: Just `section`-level will be fine.

Comment: Will you use some sort of separator, other than the actual section name, to mark where one section ends and the next one begins?

Comment: No. The thing is that new sections will necessary be at the beginning of new pages, I just want to remove the "X. Section name", as it will already be written in the header (via fancyhdr)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Something like this:

```
\newcommand\invisiblesection[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
  \sectionmark{#1}}
...

\invisiblesection{Blah}
```

Comment: Perfect ! I was missing the `\sectionmark` in what I tried before coming here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't you have an issue that several `\invisiblesection{}` in row are linked to the same (wrong) pages in the TOC or don't appear there at all?

Comment: Can you post an MWE?

Comment: any chance of getting it to work like \sectio*{} so that the counter number does not appear in the toc

Comment: Just do not `\refstepcounter`, and do not add `\numberline` to the TOC

Comment: yes that works nearly perfectly, but then it carries over the section number from the previous section (if you know what I mean). I have 4 regular sections and the i insert several invisible sections, so then my toc shows 4"name of invisible section". any chance to fix that?

Comment: Just use `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}`

Comment: thanks, that works too, but i need the section to exist as I want to print the section name in the footer (i'm using \leftmark for that)

Comment: Then use `\markboth{#1}{#1}`

Comment: Don't mean to bump old content, but if you use tools that rely on `\section` being the literal command used in source, you can still get this result by using `\def`: `\def\invisible\section#1{...}`. To get support for other sectioning commands, though, you'll have to generalize (i.e., you won't be able to define an additional `\def\invisible\subsection#1{...}`, I don't think).

Comment: I got a separate subsection command to work simply by replacing `section` with `subsection`, but I am open to more elegant solutions. Here's the command:
`\newcommand\invisiblesubsection[1]{\refstepcounter{subsection}  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#1} \sectionmark{#1}}`

Answer (score 2):

Boris' solution works well, but a `\nameref` to the section will not work correctly. Here's another that's built up on their solution.

Before `\begin{document}`

```
\makeatletter
\def\invisiblesection#1{%
\refstepcounter{section}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
\sectionmark{#1}}
\protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#1} % Set correct name
...}
\makeatother
    
\invisiblesection{Blah} \label{blah}
...
\nameref{blah}
```

Minimum working example (MWE):

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=3,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\newcommand\invisiblesectionwithoutname[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
  \sectionmark{#1}\phantom{}
  }

\makeatletter
\def\invisiblesection#1{%
\refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
  \sectionmark{#1}\phantom{}
  \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#1} % Set correct name
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}\clearpage{}

\invisiblesectionwithoutname{One} \label{one}
\begin{figure}
\caption{\protect\includegraphics{logo}}
\end{figure}


\clearpage{}
\invisiblesection{Two} \label{two}
\begin{figure}
\caption{\protect\includegraphics{logo}}
\end{figure}

\\
Without setting correct label: \nameref{one}

With setting correct label: \nameref{two}
\end{document}
```

Output (`\nameref`):

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: +1: It would be nice if you could offer a complete code example and also a screenshot of the output.