# invisible subsection

Tags: sectioning, bookmarks

I've tried adapting the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68272/make-section-headings-invisible), to make invisible subsections by changing 'section' to 'subsection' everywhere.
It didn't seem to work.
Basically, what I want is to have subsections that appear in the bookmarks menu of adobe (or other pdf readers) so that I can't jump to their location, but they shouldn't appear in the text itself.
Ideally I would prefer these subsections (or sections for that matter) didn't interfere with the numbering of regular subsections, but that's the less important part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the command `\addcontentsline` to add something to the table of contents.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{You can see this section}
\blindtext

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{You can't see this one}

\blindtext
\subsection{You can see this one!}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

This will put an unnumbered entry at the level of subsection into the `\tableofcontents` and and entry in the index! More information can be found [here](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/toc.htm).

Comment: very good! Thank you, Nethanael. Is it too much to ask that the tex editor (TeXstudio) recognize it too? :)

Comment: You _could_ make an actual invisible subsection, which would probably be recognised by TeXstudio, but that would be much more than a line long! I think I have some code at home that could work, I'll give it a look later. Still, one line answers are usually the best!