# How can I eliminate section headers, while keeping the first paragraph of each section unindented?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I would like to have the sections of my document to just be separated by a vertical space, with no visible section header. Furthermore, I would like the first paragraph of each section start without an indent.

I tried the following minimal working example for an `\invisiblesection` command, taken from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68272/make-section-headings-invisible). Unfortunately, any text that follows this `\invisiblesection` command gets indented:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\invisiblesection[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
  \sectionmark{#1}}


\begin{document}

\invisiblesection{First Section}
The section header is invisible :) but the paragraph starts with an indent :(

\section{Second Section}
The section header is visible :( but the paragraph starts with no indent :)

\end{document}
```

Adding `\noindent` to the end of `\invisiblesection` doesn't fix this. Adding `\noindent` to the beginning of each new section does fix it, but I would like this to happen automatically, as it does when I use the normal `section` environment.

Comment: A blank lines indicates a new paragraph. How do you make a new paragraph?

Comment: Can you clarify?  I think of a blank line as what defines an end of paragraph, unless I insert a `\par`.  So how do you mean a difference between "follows the previous paragraph" and "follows a blank line"?

Comment: Have you any serious reasons for breaking a five century old tradition in typography?

Comment: Sorry, that was very unclear of me. I have fixed the question. Egreg: a 40-century tradition of ignoring schoolmarms?

Comment: Add `\@afterheading` to your definition of `\invisiblesection`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel hmm, adding that gets me the following error: ! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
\@->\spacefactor 
                 \@m 
l.12 \invisiblesection{First Section}

Comment: Did you use makeatletter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED to respond to user request]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\thesection{\noindent}
\let\svsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\vspace*{-3.5\baselineskip}\svsection}
\begin{document}

\section{}

This follows a section

Second paragraph

Third paragraph

\section{}

Paragraph after new section

second paragraph

third paragraph

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Almost! Is there a way to set the vertical spacing between paragraphs? I'm getting rid of section titles to save space, so I'd like to reduce it to around 1 line.

Comment: I changed -3.5 to -2.5, and this worked perfectly (i.e. left 1 line of spacing between each section). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `titlesec` to suppress the title; here's an example where I used `fancyhdr` to show that the `\leftmark` is correctly set.

The spacing can be adjusted with `\titlespacing*{\section}...` (note the asterisk).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\section}[block]{}{}{0pt}{\@gobble}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\section{First section}

\lipsum

\section{Second section}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, when I try adjusting the vertical spacing, it seems to undo the \noindent of the first paragraph in each section. I'm using the following: 
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{0pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\renewcommand\thesection{\noindent}

Comment: @SuperElectric Sorry, you have to use `\titlespacing*` which is the version that suppresses indentation on the next paragraph.