# Don't want sections to have titles/headers

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

If you use a default section in an article like this:

```
    \section{something}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

you get the "1  something" in the toc. And your page looks like this:

```
1   something
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

I just want to have the toc entry and not the title above the section.
Because I only need the reference to the section. (It consists of a few tabulars which are self explanatory and don't need a caption/header.) I tried titlesec, but I didn't succeed.

Thanks in advance,
TJ

**EDIT:**
I want a hyperlink in my toc which refers to some page/section without a header for that section. 
Answer:

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{<title>}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! A similar question popped up some days ago: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113504/ Can you check if the answers there solve your problem? If so, please tell; otherwise, edit your question to add information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you can do something like

```
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{<title>}
```

or

```
 \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{<title>}
```

If you want a hyperlink to this, write the line

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{<title>}
```

for which you'll need to use the package `hyperref`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

\phantomsection did the trick!

I had already found the \addcontentsline. But that didn't fix the hyperlinks. Together with phantom it works.

<7 more chars>