# No section number and title be printed in PDF output in LaTex

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices, pdfpages, printing

I am using documentclass{book} to write a thesis. All my tables and figures go into the appendix, which consists of two chapters: one is Tables, another is Figures. And there are several sections in each chapter. I am using this kind of codes:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[titletoc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{CH1}
This is ch1
\section{CH1SE1}
\section{CH1SE2}
\chapter{CH2}
This is ch2
\section{CH2SE1}
\section{CH2SE2}

\begin{appendices}
 \chapter{Tables}
 \counterwithin{table}{section}
 This is appendix of tables
 \newpage
 \section{}
 \begin{table}
  \caption{parameters11}
 \end{table}
 \newpage
 \begin{table}
  \caption{parameters12}
 \end{table}
 \newpage
 \section{}
 \begin{table}
  \caption{parameters21}
 \end{table}
 \newpage
 \begin{table}
  \caption{parameters22}
 \end{table}
 \chapter{Figures}
 \counterwithin{figure}{section}
 This is appendix of figures
 \section{}
 \section{}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Run this code, one can see that on **page 8** of the PDF output, section name A.1 and Table A.1.1 are on that same page. I guess this is because the size of that table is small. However, my real tables are very large such that one table would fill out the entire page (cannot be compressed anymore since the contents will be hard to see clearly). Under this situation, the printed PDF file would have a page with only the section name A.1 on it, while that big table or figure is automatically moved to next page. For example, section name A.1 is on page 8, and on page 8 there is only A.1. Table A.1.1 will be on page 9.

Obviously I don't want a page with only a name A.1 on it. How can I keep tables and figures to be numbered within sections but completely no section numbers and titles to be printed in a PDF output. I tried \section{}* and \invisiblesection{}, they seem do not work well.

Comment: Sorry to bother you guys. I tried, and found the answer here at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68272/make-section-headings-invisible exactly solved my problem.