# Invisible addsec for running header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, koma-script

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68272/make-section-headings-invisible) post explains how to make sections invisible. Because I want to get rid of the numbers in the headers and the ToC I would like to do the same with addsec. But I cannot get this to work.

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\invisibleaddsec[1]{%
\refstepcounter{addsec}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{addsec}{\protect\numberline{\theaddsec}#1}%
\addsecmark{#1}}

\begin{document}
\invisibleaddsec{Header}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

gets an error message.

Comment: Addsec makes an unnumvered section. What number are you talking about?

Comment: If you want to get rid of numbers completely, there is a much simpler way to achieve this

Comment: I want to create an invisible addsec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously there is no counter `addsec`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\invisibleaddsec[1]{%
    \addsectiontocentry{}{#1}%
    \addsecmark{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\invisibleaddsec{Header}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! That is it.