# How to have full page figures in their own section of appendix

Tags: sectioning, appendix, fullpage

I have a structuration dilemma. The source problem is that my appendix (in a report) needs full page figures, referenced individually in the main text.

But it also has tables, and sometimes sections constituted only of text, so I place the figures inside their own section. Example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{report}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{float} % Figure placement "Here".

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\chapter{Main stuff}

\section{Stuff 1}

This is Stuff 1.

\markboth{Appendices}{}
\begin{appendices}
\floatplacement{H}

\section{Full page image}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\textheight]{example-image-b}
\caption{Full page image}
\label{appendix:img-b}
\end{figure}

\section{Other explanations}

Here come details.

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is that :

1. The figure is not displayed in the right appendix section;
2. Anyway the section title would be redundant with the figure caption;
3. If I remove the section around the figure, I won't have a TOC entry for that figure, nor the correct header marks. Also this means I have to put all appendix figures at the beginning.

*Isn't it a common situation to put full page documents in appendix? What is the canonical way to do it?*

Currently, I'm considering these options:

1. Defining invisible `section` headings inside the appendix (Then I have to write the same text as section title and as caption.) ;
2. Defining a new environment, `sectionfigure`, which just inserts a full page figure and simultaneaously starts a new section.
3. Use `\phantomsection` (from hyperref) + `\addcontentsline` to delineate the figures. This looks the simplest.

Are there better ways? If not, I will have to ask more questions about how to achieve the previous points...

**EDIT**

Currently, I "solved" my problem by defining [invisible section headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68296/95423), with a preceding `\clearpage`:

```latex
\newcommand\invisiblesection[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
  \sectionmark{#1}}
...

\clearpage{}
\invisiblesection{Full page image}
```

Comment: Figures don't appear in the TOC. Why don't you use `\listoffigures`  and no need for your `\section{Full page image}`.

Answer (score 0):

The command \textheight is the full length of text in your page. You must consider that the title will occupy some space. Also, I have specifically specified [h!] in the figure.

In summary, the following did the trick:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.8\textheight]{example-image-b}
\caption{Full page image}
\label{appendix:img-b}
\end{figure}
```

PS: I tested with 80% of \textheight and it worked, but you may have to adjust.

Comment: Precisely, I need the figure to occupy as much space as possible, ie 100% textheight.

Comment: Right, then place \pagebreak after \end{figure}. This way you will have the figure in the right section.

Comment: You can also use the package "geometry", to reduce the margins, and get more space for the image.